# How to modify languageid column in a SQLite FTS table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search, fts3, fts4

In SQLite FTS tables there is a hidden `languageid` column that I want to make use of: I need to populate my FTS4 table with rows in two different languages, which I will then distinguish by `languageid` column.

I create my table with a command like this:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE `texts` USING FTS4(`text`, tokenize=unicode61, languageid=`lid`)
```

Now how can I `INSERT` a row with a specified `languageid` if it is a *hidden* column? Or is there some other way to specify the language used in a row?

Comment: What happens if you try to specify the column in `create virtual table using (column_names)` ? See https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-text-search/

Comment: @Kendle But then it''ll be an additional "standard" column, while I wanted to use the standard `languageid` feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I had to explicitly specify the `languageid` column like this (here `lid` is the name of `languageid` column):

```
INSERT INTO `texts` (`text`,`lid`) VALUES (?,?)
```

*Sidenote: I used Python in IntelliJ IDEA for this and the IDE gave me a `Unable to resolve column 'lid'` error, but the code still worked.*